# How to avoid files that are not found (WinError 3)?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I was trying to back up my whole computer drive to google cloud storage, people mainly told me that was nonsensical, and while pondering it all, I decided just to do documents and desktop, and my goal was to use the google cloud SDK as I'm new to this and I like a challenge. So I type in:

```
gsutil -m rsync -n -J -C -e -r -u -U C:\Users\~~~~\Documents gs://~~~~-pc/documents
```

When I send that, I receive this message:

> Caught non-retryable exception while listing file://C:\Users~~~~~\Documents: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\Users\~~~~~\Documents\~~~~~~~~~ Files\2015 NEGOTIATIONIS\2105 NEGOTIATIONS FILE - MAIN\Implementation\Temporary Transfers and Permanet Involuntary Force Rearragement\Temporary Transfers and Permanent Involuntary Force Rearrangement FINAL October 3 2014.docx'
> CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync

**Please Help!!!**

*Note: "~" is for censorship*

Edit: I did a debug, and I don't know what anything meant, here's an output that doesn't show my personal data:

```
Caught non-retryable exception while listing file://C:\Users\~~~~\Documents: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\~~~~\\Documents\\~~~~ Files\\2015 NEGOTIATIONIS\\2105 NEGOTIATIONS FILE - MAIN\\Implementation\\Temporary Transfers and Permanet Involuntary Force Rearragement\\Temporary Transfers and Permanent Involuntary Force Rearrangement FINAL October 3 2014.docx'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 653, in _ListUrlRootFunc
    out_file)
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 903, in _BatchSort
    current_chunk = sorted(islice(in_iter, buffer_size))
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 734, in _FieldedListingIterator
    for blr in iterator:
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 701, in IterObjects
    bucket_listing_fields=bucket_listing_fields):
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 721, in IterAll
    bucket_listing_fields=bucket_listing_fields):
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 611, in __iter__
    blr_object = _GetFileObject(filepath) if include_size else None
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\wildcard_iterator.py", line 531, in _GetFileObject
    return apitools_messages.Object(size=os.path.getsize(filepath))
  File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\genericpath.py", line 50, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\~~~~\\Documents\\~~~~ Files\\2015 NEGOTIATIONIS\\2105 NEGOTIATIONS FILE - MAIN\\Implementation\\Temporary Transfers and Permanet Involuntary Force Rearragement\\Temporary Transfers and Permanent Involuntary Force Rearrangement FINAL October 3 2014.docx'

DEBUG: Exception stack trace:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\__main__.py", line 634, in _RunNamedCommandAndHandleExceptions
        user_project=user_project)
      File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\command_runner.py", line 411, in RunNamedCommand
        return_code = command_inst.RunCommand()
      File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 1657, in RunCommand
        diff_iterator = _DiffIterator(self, src_url, dst_url)
      File "C:\Users\~~~~\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\gsutil\gslib\commands\rsync.py", line 999, in __init__
        raise CommandException('Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync')
    gslib.exception.CommandException: CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
```

Comment: I'll add my voice to that of others who've cautioned you about using this approach. As you've seen, your approach is problematic and the risk is that you'll think you've backed up a file but haven't. There are many proven backup solutions (some of which using Google Cloud Storage) that will work well for you. That all said, if you're committed to this approach, the challenge appears to be some combination of the difference between Windows' and Linux's file systems. Space in names are *frequently* problematic. You may wish to try `rsync`'s `--protect-args` flag.

Comment: Please ensure you read **all** the caveats here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is caused by MAX_PATH. The default is 260 characters.

**Method 1 - Specify UNC Paths**

Prefix paths with `"\\?\"`. This changes maximum path names to 32,767 characters.

```
\\?\C:\Users\~~~~\Documents
```

**Method 2 - Change the Windows Registry**

To solve your problem requires editing the registry to support longer path names up to 32,767 characters.

Change this registry key:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\FileSystem\LongPathsEnabled
Type: REG_DWORD
Value: 1
```

Read this document for more information:

[Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)