# Terraform The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

> **What specific configuration or syntax changes must be made in order to resolve the `The system cannot find the path specified.` error that terraform is throwing when it tries to load a provider from a local mirror?**

**THE PROBLEM**

A local file system mirror for terraform providers is re-used in an automation program.

1. The console prints out `The system cannot find the path specified.` during the third use of the same provider by the third module that tries to download the module within 2 minutes.
2. The first two times the same provider is requested from the same local file system mirror succeed within a couple minutes before this error is thrown.
3. The problem persists when the calling program sleeps 360 seconds before each request in an attempt to avoid possible locking causes.  6 minute delay does not prevent problem.

**THE PROVIDER EXE FILE EXISTS**

The `terraform-provider-aws_v3.22.0_x5.exe` provider file does indeed appear when we view it in Windows Explorer.  Then, we we right click on the exe file and open the properties window, the location and file name are given as:

```
C:\projects\TERRAF~1\29DEC2~1\TERRAF~2\CALLS-~1\INSTAN~1\SUBNET~1\DEMO-D~1\TERRAF~1\PROVID~1\REGIST~1.IO\HASHIC~1\aws\322~1.0\WINDOW~1
```

Then when we run a `dir` command to explore the directory, we also see the following:

```
C:\path\to\some\directory>dir C:\projects\TERRAF~1\29DEC2~1\TERRAF~2\CALLS-~1\INSTAN~1\SUBNET~1\DEMO-D~1\TERRAF~1\PROVID~1\REGIST~1.IO\HASHIC~1\aws\322~1.0\WINDOW~1
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is DAB2-5285

 Directory of C:\projects\TERRAF~1\29DEC2~1\TERRAF~2\CALLS-~1\INSTAN~1\SUBNET~1\DEMO-D~1\TERRAF~1\PROVID~1\REGIST~1.IO\HASHIC~1\aws\322~1.0\WINDOW~1

12/29/2020  01:36 PM    <DIR>          .
12/29/2020  01:36 PM    <DIR>          ..
12/29/2020  01:36 PM       175,883,264 terraform-provider-aws_v3.22.0_x5.exe
           1 File(s)    175,883,264 bytes
           2 Dir(s)  736,395,243,520 bytes free
```

**COMPLETE STACK TRACE**

The complete TRACE output of the terraform command is as follows:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: C:\path\to\terraform\providers is a symlink to C:\path\to\terraform\providers
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 for windows_amd64 at C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/http v2.0.0 for windows_amd64 at C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\http\2.0.0\windows_amd64
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] providercache.Dir.InstallPackage: installing registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 from C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.22.0...
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: scanning directory .terraform\providers
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: .terraform\providers is a symlink to .terraform\providers
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 for windows_amd64 at .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64
2020/12/29 13:36:35 [TRACE] providercache.fillMetaCache: error while scanning directory .terraform\providers: cannot search .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-aws_v3.22.0_x5.exe: CreateFile .terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64\terraform-provider-aws_v3.22.0_x5.exe: The system cannot find the path specified.

Error: Failed to install provider
```

**@JohnHanley's SUGGESTION**

Per @JohnHanley's suggestion in the comments, we reset the `` registry key to `1` and then opened a different instance of Windows CMD, navigated to the same directory, and ran the same automation program.

The program now stops at the same place as before, but this time the program hangs in definitely instead of explicitly throwing an error.

Here is the new console output up to the point where it hangs:

```
Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding latest version of hashicorp/aws...
2020/12/29 15:39:21 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: C:\path\to\terraform\providers is a symlink to C:\path\to\terraform\providers
2020/12/29 15:39:21 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 for windows_amd64 at C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64
2020/12/29 15:39:21 [TRACE] getproviders.SearchLocalDirectory: found registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/http v2.0.0 for windows_amd64 at C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\http\2.0.0\windows_amd64
2020/12/29 15:39:21 [TRACE] providercache.Dir.InstallPackage: installing registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v3.22.0 from C:\path\to\terraform\providers\registry.terraform.io\hashicorp\aws\3.22.0\windows_amd64
- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.22.0...
```

Comment: I think you have hit the MAX_PATH limit of 260 characters. You are also using the DOS namespace for your file names. Either rearrange your folder structure for shorter path lengths or refer to my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65279356/8016720

Comment: @JohnHanley I just reset the key.  Rerunning now.  Stay tuned.

Comment: @JohnHanley With that registry key set, the same automation program now still stops at the same place, but this time it hangs indefinitely with the last line in the console as `- Installing hashicorp/aws v3.22.0...`, which is different than before when the program immediately threw an explicit error at this same place.

Comment: Did you change from the DOS namespace to LONG? Names like this `TERRAF~1` are in the DOS namespace. Recreate your paths to be long file name (LFN) compatible. I also recommend rebooting your system after changing the registry.

Comment: @JohnHanley I changed the registry key, but this program might not have an application manifest as this is a Python3 script in its current incarnation.

Comment: What does an application manifest have to do with path names and name spaces and terraform? Terraform is not a Python script.

Comment: @JohnHanley  I will reboot the system now, but note the entire path and file name is 258 characters by my count.  A Python script is calling terraform repeatedly.  Your link describing how to change to LFN compatible stated that both the registry key and the application manifest must be changed.  I set the registry key but do not know how to address the application manifest instructions in this case.  I will be back in a few after I reboot and then rerun the automation.

Comment: The path is way longer than 258 characters. Your file names are using the DOS namespace which means the LONG name equivalent is much longer. You need to correct that to use normal names under Windows which is the LONG namespace.

Comment: @JohnHanley I counted every character in the path and file name including the `.exe` ending, and it came to 258.  In any event, I have rebooted the machine and I have rerun the program and it still hangs up in the same place as described at the end of my edited OP.  This worked without problem before trying the local `filesystem_mirror` for providers.  Also, the first two calls that work correctly mentioned in the OP might have only 5 to 15 fewer characters than this one.

Comment: Post an answer once you figure this out.

Comment: For the DOS namespace applications typically have 255 as the max length. For the long namespace the directory name cannot exceed MAX_PATH minus 12. The terminating NULL takes one space.

Comment: @JohnHanley The solution was to shorten all the paths.  I counted 18 characters that I trimmed, but the number to shorten is relative to the max of course.  This problem did not exist when providers were retrieved from remote registries.  This problem only emerged when a `terraform.rc` file was added to specify a local `filesystem_mirror`.  If you want to type up an answer, I would be happy to mark it as accepted to help others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error messages indicate a MAX_PATH problem. A side issue is that the path is using the DOS namespace. The solution is to either reorganize the directory structure to shorten the path or use UNC Paths.

For the DOS namespace, applications are often coded to support a maximum length of 255 characters. For the LONG namespace the maximum length is 260 characters of which the directory portion cannot exceed MAX_PATH - 12 (248) characters. The terminating NULL consumes one character.

[Enable Long Paths in Windows 10, Version 1607, and Later](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/maximum-file-path-limitation#enable-long-paths-in-windows-10-version-1607-and-later)